# Wrong number of lifetime parameters when nesting lifetime inside Vec

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build a structure that contains references to a vector of another struct like this:

```
pub struct Downstream<'a> {
    frequency: i32,
    slot: i32,
    connector: i32,
    description: String,
    cablemac: &'a CableMac,
}

pub struct Upstream<'a> {
    downstreams: Vec<Downstream>,
}
```

Whatever I try, I always get this lifetime error:

```
src/e6000/mod.rs:13:22: 13:32 error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
src/e6000/mod.rs:13     downstreams: Vec<Downstream>,
```

E0107 doesn't help at all.

Where and how so I put an `'a` to get this working?

Comment: *E0107 doesn't help at all.* — The compiler **tells** you how to get more information: "help: run `rustc --explain E0107` to see a detailed explanation". Read the *entire* compiler message.

Answer (score 3):

```
downstreams: Vec<Downstream>,
```

should be

```
downstreams: Vec<Downstream<'a>>,
```

---

> E0107 doesn't help at all.

You should run `rustc --explain E0107`.

The output of that command currently starts with some nice examples:

> This error means that an incorrect number of lifetime parameters were
>   provided for a type (like a struct or enum) or trait.
>
> Some basic examples include:
>
> ```
> struct Foo<'a>(&'a str);
> enum Bar { A, B, C }
>
> struct Baz<'a> {
>     foo: Foo,     // error: expected 1, found 0
>     bar: Bar<'a>, // error: expected 0, found 1
> }
> ```

Comment: I don't know how to adapt this example to Vec<T>. Whatever I tried I'm getting errors. I tried Vec<'a Downstream>, Vec<'a><Downstream> and I'm still getting errors.

Comment: Thanks ! My problem was that lifetime 'a marker is often before element. I didn't thought to put it behind.

Comment: @MrSpock: Before and after are completely different. `&'a T` is a reference to a `T` with a lifetime `'a` while `Blabla<A, B>` is a type `Blabla` with two generic parameters `A` and `B` which may be either types or lifetimes. A reference to the `Downstream<'a>` type would be `&'b Downstream<'a>`. The name `Downstream` alone is not a type, it's incomplete without its full list of generic parameters; it is just that sometimes the compilers allows you not to note them down because it figures them out.